# 12 hour clock in python datetime module, PM and AM not effecting datetime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I want to convert a string to a datetime class object, but for some reason the PM and AM does not effect the final result. What I want is that if it is PM, 12h would be added to the hours

Format → `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p`
Example → `12/11/2020 8:25:52 PM`

Problem:

```py
import datetime as tm
ts = tm.datetime.strptime('12/11/2020 8:25:52 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
ts2 = tm.datetime.strptime('12/11/2020 8:25:52 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
print(ts2)
print(ts == ts2)
```

Output:

```
2020-11-12 08:25:52
True
```

Comment: Change %H to %I

Comment: As mentioned, %H is for 24h foramt and %I is for 12h format.
Read the table at https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

Comment: Everyday you learn something new, thanks for the answers : )

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine if you change the `%H` to `%I` since `%H` is is the "24-hour" format,

```
 import datetime as tm
    ts = tm.datetime.strptime('12/11/2020 8:25:52 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    ts2 = tm.datetime.strptime('12/11/2020 8:25:52 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    print(ts2)
    print(ts == ts2)
```